# PyQt - how to stop execution without closing the dialog window

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have  one dialog window with various linEdits and buttons which call various functions.
One button sends various signals and when an exception/error occurs, it closes the whole window.
I have found some similar cases, but this one is specific in having various signals.

Now this is the code where I want to check if the path in line edit and the files exist. If not I would like to display the message and keep the dialog window open. So handle the error without executing further signals and closing the window. `sys.exit()` unfortunately closes the whole window.

This is what I have so far:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog, QLabel, QCheckBox, QWidget, QMessageBox
from os.path import expanduser

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(450, 39)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 10, 311, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.checkfolder)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.checkfilexist)        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Runnormal)


        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Click"))



    def checkfolder(self):
        try:
            import sys
            import os
            import glob
            import ctypes
            didi = self.lineEdit.text()
            if  os.path.exists(didi):
                print(didi)
                pass
            elif not os.path.exists(didi):
                ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Enter the existing path!", "ERROR", 1)
                return

        except Exception as exc:
            traceback.print_exc()
            raw_input()


    def checkfilexist(self):
        try:
            import sys
            import os
            import glob
            import ctypes
            didi = self.lineEdit.text()
            fufu = didi + '/' + '*USR02.txt'
            if  glob.glob(fufu):
                print(didi)
                pass
            elif not os.path.isfile(fufu):
                ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "No files found, please try again!", "ERROR", 1)
                return

        except Exception as exc:
            traceback.print_exc()
            raw_input()


#clean the files to obtain headers
    def Runnormal(self):
        try:
            import os
            bad_words = {'--------', 'Table:', 'Displayed Fields:', 'Dynamic List Display'}
            didi = self.lineEdit.text()
#            print(didi)
            for filename in os.listdir(didi):            
                    if filename.endswith("DEVACCESS.txt"):
#                        print(filename)
                        filepath = os.path.join(didi, filename)
                        with open(filepath, errors='ignore') as oldfile, open(didi + "\\clean_" + filename, 'w') as newfile:
#                            print(oldfile)
#                            print(newfile)
                            for line in oldfile:
                                if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
                                    newfile.write(line)

        except Exception as exc:
            traceback.print_exc()
            raw_input()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When the path does not exist, or the file exists - the code does not stop, but passes to the third signal and fails/closes the window.

How to handle errors/stop executing script without closing the dialog window or not passing to the other button signals? Basically, stop after the first or second signal without closing the whole window.

Comment: Can you edit your question, enclosing all your code into a single [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Your implementation seems a bit confused, and with only bits and pieces of your code it's very hard to understand what's wrong and help you.

Comment: Basically I want to prevent the window closing on error/or passing to the subsequent signals where it fails. I want error handling that does not close the dialog window. Unfortunately `sys.exit()` does that.

Comment: The problem you're getting might come from a moltitude of problems, including wrong indentation or function definitions; we need a minimal reproducible example, without that it's just guessing starting from bits of code we know very little about. Take your time, read the link I posted in my previous comment, and edit your question to include an example we can relate to.

Comment: @Kokokoko What you have provided is not an MRE, an MRE must give us the ability to make a copy-paste, execute the code and then get the same error you get, and clearly the pieces of code are not.

Comment: @eyllanesc this should be working now. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that the first two defs or signals are enough to meet the condition, can this actually work? Calling the signal from the `def checkfilexist` and let the next signal call the subsequent one or just give an error message.

```
def checkfilexist(self):
    try:
        import sys
        import os
        import glob
        import ctypes
        didi = self.lineEdit.text()
        fufu = didi + '/' + '*USR02.txt'
        if  glob.glob(fufu):
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Runnormal)

        elif not os.path.isfile(fufu):
            ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "No files found, please try again!", "ERROR", 1)
            return
```

Comment: this is an answer?

Comment: Only in case there is no other way how to universally stop the code from execution without quitting the dialog window. And that's what I would like to know.